# Adding 1 hour to lightning:input type="datetime"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, aura

I have an aura component which is constructed like this

```
<aura:attribute name="newEvent" type="Event" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Event'}"/>

<lightning:input
    aura:id="startdatetime"
    type="datetime"
    label="Start Time"
    name="start"
    value="{!v.newEvent.startTime}"
    required="true"
/>

<lightning:input
    aura:id="enddatetime"
    type="datetime"
    label="End Time"
    name="end"
    value="{!v.newEvent.endTime}"
    required="true"
/>
```

How do I add 1 hour to end date time based from start date time? For example start date time is 20/07/2022 3:10 pm, I want the end date time to be 20/07/2022 4:10 pm and set it to input field as default value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Date class in JavaScript to do this in just a couple lines of code:

```
const theTime = new Date(component.find("startdatetime").get("v.value"));
theTime.setHours(theTime.getHours()+1);
component.find("enddatetime").set("v.value", theTime.toGMTString()));
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, your answer doesn't work on my end. It's saying Invalid date when I try logging it. Here's a gif when I try your solution. https://gyazo.com/3883c6d1e64df29e52a40d823911e3b6

Comment: Thanks for updating @sfdcfox, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve that using split mechanism of start date input value and added the 1 into hour representation of it. The datetime input has value in format `2020-09-12T00:00:00Z`, I fetched the hours by splitting it using **`T`**. It has been spitted again using **`:`** so that we can get the hour value from it. After adding 1, I created the end time string and set the value programmatically onload of the component.

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        let startfield = component.find("startdatetime");
        let startdate = startfield.get("v.value").split("T")[0];
        let starttime = startfield.get("v.value").split("T")[1];
        let starthour = starttime.split(":")[0];
        let endhour = parseInt(starthour)+1;
        let endminandmilisecond = starttime.split(":")[1]+':'+starttime.split(":")[2];
        let endfield = component.find("enddatetime");
        if(endhour < 10){
            endhour = '0'+endhour;
        }
        endfield.set("v.value",startdate+'T'+endhour+':'+endminandmilisecond);
        console.log(startfield.get("v.value"),endfield.get("v.value"));
    },
})
```

Comment: Hi @sanket-kumar, your solution works. Thank you for answering my question. I wish I could upvote  your answer, my reputation is still low.

Comment: You could have written this in just 3-5 lines of code.

Comment: I am wondering, does this method work well with 12 or 24 hour? I mean when the hour has to be reset back to 0 or 1?

Comment: @sfdcfox I completely forgot about parsing to date type. Thanks for the correction.